# How to make users edit field.options in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am making an app where users can track their income and expenses. I want each transaction to be categorized based on where it is stored - like in checking, credit, savings, wallet, gift card, venmo, etc.

I am planning to use Django [Field.choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#:%7E:text=will%20be%20required.-,choices,-%C2%B6) but the options are permanent and I want the users to edit their own choices.

How can I do that?

Comment: Create another model to store user's categories/locations?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that you can use is to have a separated table with those categories and use `models.ForeignKey` instead.

[django Documentation models.ForeignKeye](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)